# Mongo return in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following n to n (done with mongoid gem) with two collections books and publishers:

```
{
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA",
   books: [123456789, 234567890, ...]
}

{
    _id: 123456789,
    title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
    author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
    published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
    pages: 216,
    language: "English"
}

{
   _id: 234567890,
   title: "50 Tips and Tricks for MongoDB Developer",
   author: "Kristina Chodorow",
   published_date: ISODate("2011-05-06"),
   pages: 68,
   language: "English"
}
```

I need to return in one query the publishers, but separated in documents, like this:

```
{
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA",
   book: 123456789 # or books:[123456789]
}
{
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   founded: 1980,
   location: "CA",
   book: 234567890 # or books:[123456789
}
```

I want to this inside mongo in a query, actually I do it in the rabl file modifying the collection, but this is not good por gaination and using in other representations, So I want to do this transformation in Mongo, not in ruby, Or maybe I should change the query calling for books instead on publishers.

This is the code in ruby:

```
@publishers is a mongoid::Criteria

@publishers = @publishers.collect do |s|
  s.books.count > 1 ? s.publisher_separate_by_books : s
end.flatten

class Publisher
   has_and_belongs_to_many :books, inverse_of: :books, dependent: :nullify
 def publisher_separate_by_books
    books.map {|i| Publisher.new({name: name, founded: founded, location: location, books: [i]})} 
  end
end
```

How can achieve this in mongo query

Comment: you better not put data representation logic in model. there are special gems to help with you that

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage to expanding the query result like that in the database server (any database server). If you wanted to perform additional operations per book in the query (which in case of MongoDB would involve the aggregation pipeline, and for relational databases JOIN operations) then it would make sense. But simply expanding a field like that in the database is wasteful.

MongoDB does support this operation via unwind (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind), but then you lose the ability to query the models using DSL provided by Mongoid and have to construct the aggregation pipelines instead.